# RoR Tutorial Hartl Chapter 7.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stuck here in the tutorial,section 7.3, it says the test should pass at the end  but it still fails when i run bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "signup with invalid information".

```
 $ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "signup with invalid information"
Run options: include {:full_description=>/signup\ with\ invalid\ information/}
F

Failures:

  1) User pages signup with invalid information should not create a user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
     ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
       ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.13176 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:27 # User pages signup with invalid information should not create a user

Randomized with seed 31885
```

Here's my /spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
   describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end
  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

heres the users_controller.rb file

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
   def new
    @user = User.new
  end
 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
   private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

and my new.html.erb file

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just show me the output of `p User.column_names` ?

Comment: `2.0.0-p481 :001 > p User.column_names
["id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest"]
 => ["id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest"]`

Comment: Now you see, your DB don't have same columns, which you have used here  `permit(:name, :email, :password,:password_confirmation)` . There is the problem.

Comment: I wanted to teach you how to debug.. :-) Go and Fix it.

Comment: aren't those the attributes that the users input when they signup? why do they have to be the same as the DB columns @ArupRakshit